# content attr of outer tags

Tags: version-control, element

Well in SCSS, something like this

```
obj {
  obj2 {
    content: attr(val) ; /**/
  }
}
```

Where the "val" attribute is set in "obj", and not "obj2". How to use the attributes from the outside elements?

This will be an example of the html content:

```
<obj val="$">
  <obj2>a</obj>
  <obj2>b</obj>
  <obj2>c</obj>
</obj>
```

Comment: Does the no-answers mean that nobody understands the question?

Answer (score 0):

`content: "";` is used for pseudo-elements (`:before`, `:after`) and not for regular elements like `<obj2>`.
You cannot access the attributes of a parent element from the child, so in the HTML you described you would not be able to get the attribute val.

You should set up a structure like:

**HTML**

```
<obj currency="USD">
  <obj2>1</obj2>
  <obj2>2</obj2>
  <obj2>3</obj2>
</obj>
```

**SCSS**

```
obj {
    /*Stylings*/
    obj2{
        /*Stylings*/
    }
    &[currency="USD"]>*:before {
        content:'$';
    }
    &[currency="GBP"]>*:before {
        content:'£';
    }
    &[currency="EUR"]>*:before {
        content:'€';
    } 
}
```

---

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
obj {
  /*Stylings*/
}
obj obj2 {
  /*Stylings*/
}
obj[currency="USD"] > *:before {
  content: '$';
}
obj[currency="GBP"] > *:before {
  content: '£';
}
obj[currency="EUR"] > *:before {
  content: '€';
}
```

```html
<obj currency="USD">
  <obj2>1</obj2>
  <obj2>2</obj2>
  <obj2>3</obj2>
</obj>
```